# Impute nulls of grouped by aggregate for PromQL group by query

Tags: prometheus, grafana, promql

Right now I am computing the `minimum_over_time` for 1 day long intervals of a query that has been given placeholder selector names. When I compute the result, there are nulls in some of the groups. Currently, my query has the following structure:

```
(
  min_over_time(
    min 
      without(instance) 
      (app_traffic_usage{
            job=~"mobile|desktop",
            environment="production"})[1d:5m])
  or by (job) vector(0)
)
```

Ideally, I would like the OR statement to impute for each job individually, but because vector has no label, it does not work. Would appreciate any help on the matter. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try swapping `min` with `min_over_time`:

```
min(
  min_over_time(app_traffic_usage{
    job=~"mobile|desktop",
    environment="production"}[1d]
  )
) without (instance)
```

This query works in the following way:

1. It finds the minimum raw sample values per each matching series during the last day.
2. Then it finds the minimum values per each group of series from the step 1  grouped by all the labels except `instance` label.

The difference between this query and the original query from the question is that the original query uses [Prometheus subquery feature](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#subqueries). While this feature is powerful, it is hard to understand and use properly :( It looks like it was improperly used here.

As for the universal way for filling gaps with zeroes in arbitrary time series, the `or vector(0)` idiom doesn't work as expected in complex cases. In these cases you can use `default 0` idiom from [MetricsQL](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html) if you use VictoriaMetrics instead of Prometheus. This is Prometheus-like system I work on.